# Putting a space between images within a table

Tags: php, html, datatable

Ive got a datatable working correctly, in my 'Actions' column I am displaying images for users to edit/delete etc.

However the images are very close together, how would I put a couple of spaces between them?

Im using the following code to display the images;

```
$row[2] =   "
    <td><a onClick =\"return confirm('Are You Sure You Want To Edit This Ticket?')\" href=$edit>
    <img src=\"edit.png\">
    <td><a onClick =\"return confirm('Are You Sure You Want To Delete This Ticket?')\" href=$delete>
    <img src=\"delete.png\">";
```

Please let me know on how I could put a space between the two?

Thanks

Comment: Use either <td> <a.... or <td>&nbsp;<a.... you could use CSS but that would affect the whole table.

Comment: You're not closing your table column tags. As jeff said, use CSS but target images only and give them margins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) you can alter the appearance of HTML elements.

For example:

```
<style type="text/css">
.spaced {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}
</style>

$row[2] =   "<td><a class=\"spaced\" onClick =\"return confirm('Are You Sure You Want To Edit This Ticket?')\" href=$edit><img src=\"edit.png\"><td><a onClick =\"return confirm('Are You Sure You Want To Delete This Ticket?')\" href=$delete><img src=\"delete.png\">";
```

Comment: this is putting them under eachother rather than on the same line with a space?

Comment: My mistake. `block` needs to be changed to `inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

You can try add 
    `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` between the image. This example I add 3 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
$row[2] =   "<td><a onClick =\"return confirm('Are You Sure You Want To Edit This Ticket?')\" href=$edit><img src=\"edit.png\"><td><a onClick =\"return confirm('Are You Sure You Want To Delete This Ticket?')\" href=$delete><img src=\"delete.png\" style="padding:5px;">";
```

Try this